# How to redirect traffic that comes from certain url to another using IIS - Web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, .htaccess, redirect, web-config

This .htaccess file is exactly what i need.

However im running ASP.net and I need the exact code for the Web.Config

/ / / / / / / / .htaccess code / / / / / / / / /

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} referrerURL\.com/
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.redirectedURL.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not install  http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/ or http://www.helicontech.com/download-ape.htm (depending on your version of IIS) to give you .htaccess functionality?